# I sneeze, I snoze

Tags: verbs

This has really been keeping me up at night. If the past tense of freeze is froze, then how come the past tense of sneeze isn't snoze?

Comment: Because `freeze` is an irregular verb, but `sneeze` isn't. There's no logic to irregulars, that's what makes them irregular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irregular verbs are historically old verbs with a conjugation system of their own.
But it would be very impractical if every verb would be irregular. In the course of time a newer and simpler conjugation system developed, much easier to handle.
So it happens that an old verb like to freeze has vowel change in its three stem forms and a verb like to sneeze which developed much later is regular.

Etymonline has the information that to freeze can already be found in Old English 
(5th to 11th century) and there are related forms in other Indo-European languages.

The earliest finds of to sneeze are from the late 15th century.

The old class of irregular verbs is limited, roughly about 2oo. A great part of these has become obsolete. So that we have roughly a hundred active irregular verbs and we see that there is a process to diminish the number of irregular verbs. Such verbs as to learn/learnt/learnt are regular in AmE. And some verbs as to abide are becoming rare.